# Cast values to integer while filter strings that contain special characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, filter

I have data with a long list of string, and I would like to cast them to an integer, but still keep some strings that contain special characters:`x`, `.`, `...` as string. May someone help me filter the strings has special characters?

List of strings:

```
Type  Values
str   1
str   1
str   1
str   1
str   0
str   10.0.0.21
float nan
str   0
str   38082
str   -10
str   -12
str   0xE0020000
```

Expected type:

```
Type  Values
Int   1
Int   1
Int   1
Int   1
Int   0
Str   10.0.0.21
Float nan
Int   0
Int   38082
Int   -10
Int   -12
Str   0xE0020000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your list of strings, you can traverse the list and cast all numeric values to an `int`:

```
input_values = ['1', '1', '1', '1', 
                '0', '10.0.0.21', 
                float('nan'), '0', '38083']

def cast_to_int(word):
    if type(word) == str and word.isnumeric():
        return int(word)

    return word

list(map(cast_to_int, input_values))
```

**Update:**

If you have negative values in your `input_values` then you will need to use the following solution.

```
def cast_to_int(word):
    try:
        return int(word)
    except ValueError:
        return word

list(map(cast_to_int, input_values))
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works, but in my list of data, it also has negative numbers, such as: -12, -10... Currenly, their type changes to string as well. How to keep it as Int?

Comment: Ok. I see. I already pressed '✓'. Sorry. I though votes is accepted.